# How to merge two data stes by date and ID, and with specific parameters in the date range

Tags: r, date, join

I want to merge two data sets by ID and date. I want the dates in set B to be within 1 week of set A. I also want the earliest date (within 1 week) from set B to be merged to set A. Also, if there are multiple dates within 1 week, do not join multiple observations from set B to set A in a given range and ID.

What would the code look like for this? Would this be a left join if I wanted to prioritize set A?

**Set A:**

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-21-2021 |
| 2 | 03-03-2020 |

**Set B:**

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-22-2021 |
| 2 | 03-04-2020 |
| 1 | 10-23-2021 |

For example, the first two rows of set B would be joined to set A, but the final row would not because only one row within a week can be joined by each row in set A.

Comment: Could you please provide some example data, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/17303805)?

Comment: Example data is now given.

Comment: When >1 date is within a week, how do you want to pick which to keep? What if there are multiple equidistant dates, e.g. for 10-21-2021, both 10-20-2021 and 10-22-2021?

Comment: Thank you for posing the question. Thankfully that won't but the case very often in my data set, but I would want to pick the dates that occur after in set B. So if there is 10-21-2021 in set A it would select 10-22-2021 in set B.

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge in all set B dates for each `ID`.
2. Compute the days between each pair of dates.
3. Filter out dates > 7 days away.
4. Within each `ID` and `Date_A`, select the row with the lowest `Days_Diff` and (in case of ties) latest `Date_B`.

```r
library(dplyr)

set_A %>% 
  left_join(set_B, by = "ID", suffix = c("_A", "_B")) %>% 
  mutate(Days_Diff = abs(as.numeric(Date_B - Date_A, unit = "days"))) %>% 
  filter(Days_Diff <= 7) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date_A) %>%
  slice(order(Days_Diff, desc(Date_B))[[1]]) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(!Days_Diff) # remove helper column

#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>      ID Date_A     Var_A Date_B     Var_B
#>   <dbl> <date>     <chr> <date>     <chr>
#> 1     1 2021-10-21 a     2021-10-22 W    
#> 2     2 2020-03-03 b     2020-03-04 X
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Data**

Note I added a few extra columns and test cases to the data provided by OP.

```r
set_A <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~Date, ~Var_A,
    1, "2021-10-21",    "a",
    2, "2020-03-03",    "b"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

set_B <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~Date, ~Var_B,
    1, "2021-10-22",    "W",
    2, "2020-03-04",    "X",
    1, "2021-10-23",    "Y",
    2, "2020-03-02",    "Z"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
```

Comment: If I had other relevant columns I wanted to include from each data set, how would I include them?